# documents get elements by classname apply to all element

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JS. I want to change css for all elements selected by className. I did some search and I found the solution below. But, it will only affect the first element. I am wondering if there is a easy to to change the css for all selected elements.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ads')[0].style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: I would recommend you to watch [this](https://css-tricks.com/lodge/learn-jquery/) learning series for jQuery, it's something I wish that I would've watched sooner to get inte jQuery first then eventually switch to pure Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('class')[x]
```

may be x can be 0,1,2,... depends on elements with that class if there two `div` with `ads`
class you will count from 0 as the first div with that class because it returns in array
or you can use tag name while you are selecting

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[x]
```

this also returns in array because in html suppose to be many similar tags means that you have to index to them

```
document.getElementById('id')
```

this is selecting by using the tag's id and an id there a tag with an id should be the unique thats why this doesn't return in array means that you don't need to index on it

```
document.querySelectorAll('p .class')[x]
```

with selector you do it like you do in css but it returns in array to and also you can apply the pseudo classes and elements

```
document.querySelector('p .class')
```

this used like the above one but it didn't return in array so you don't have to index on it

Comment: and you can continue the about the selectors here if you appreciate https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp and if you this helps you can vote and accept it otherwise downvote it help to me and others

Answer (score 0):

```
NodeList.prototype.forEach = NodeList.prototype.forEach || Array.prototype.forEach;
document.querySelectorAll('.ads').forEach(ele => {ele.style.display = 'none'});
```

This should do it. The `querySelectorAll`-method returns you a Nodelist from a given `css-selector`. The first line checks if there is already a `forEach` method and if not it will inherit it from the `Array` Object.
You can also read about the `from` method of the `Array` object this could be a more cleaner version.

Comment: You can skip the first line if you don't care about old browsers or "Internet Explorer".
As you see here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Answer (score 0):

You need to use loop, please check snippet

NOTE: I added **'.hide'** class and set `background color` just to display result. you just add `display:none` in CSS

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var ads = document.getElementsByClassName("ads"),
        len = ads !== null ? ads.length : 0,
        i = 0;
    for(i; i < len; i++) {
        ads[i].className += " hide"; 
    }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="ads">1</div>
<div class="ads">2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple with jQuery method :

```
$('.ads:first').hide();
```

```
$('.ads:first').css("display":"none");
```

To using jQuery, you have to add jQuery plugin inside **<body>** tag before jQuery function call :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```